# looping check button and getting its value

Tags: python, tkinter

**Creating check-button using for loop and extracting the value (whether it is checked or unchecked)**
Hello all,
I am a beginner to python GUI and planning to create a GUI with many check-buttons and write the value of each check-button in a text file on clicking a submit button.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

fields_output=["option 01","option 02","option 03","option 04","option 05","option 06","option 07","option 08","option 09","option 10","option 11"]

def my_function_01():
    f = open("C:\\Users\\atulh\\Desktop\\Atul_Python\\demofile2.txt", "a")
    f.write("Following is the summary !")
    f.write("\n")
    r=0
    for each_field in fields_output:
        f.write(each_field + " = " )
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()


root = tk.Tk()

frame_lh =LabelFrame(root, text="Field Outputs")
frame_lh.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

r=0
for each_field in range(len(fields_output)):
    tk.Checkbutton(frame_lh,text=fields_output[each_field],).grid(row=r, sticky=W)
    r=r+1

b = tk.Button(root,text="Submit_data",command=my_function_01()).grid(row=1,column=1)
```

Comment: Is your code not working?  If so, what is it doing?

Comment: it was not, but with the help from figbeam it is function well now, thank you all for the support, i am not a programmer, but just wanted a small GUI for a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

Import tkinter only once. Several imports of the same module may become confusing. Importing as `tk` is the usual way.

To get the states of the Checkbuttons you'll have to associate each one with a variable, and then save references to all these variables. I have saved them to a dictionary with the field as key.

I changed the for loop to be more Pythonic. The loop is over the `fields_output` list and the `enumerate()` function generates the index starting from 0.

In the loop I associate each Checkbutton with a `BooleanVar()` and save a reference to the button_dict. Later the `my_function_01()` uses the button_dict to get the states of all the Checkbuttons.

Added `root.mainloop()` at the end. If you are developing the program in IDLE the program will work regardless using the mainloop in IDLE. But the program may not run outside your development environment.

I changed the file path and the options list.

```
import tkinter as tk

fields_output = ["option 01", "option 02", "option 03", "option 04"]

def my_function_01():
    f = open("demofile2.txt", "a")
    f.write("Following is the summary !")
    f.write("\n")
    for field in fields_output:
        f.write(field + " = " + str(button_dict[field].get()))
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()


root = tk.Tk()

frame_lh = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Field Outputs")
frame_lh.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=10, pady=10)

button_dict = {}
for index, field in enumerate(fields_output):
    var = tk.BooleanVar()   # Create a variable for each Checkbutton
    c = tk.Checkbutton(frame_lh, text=field, variable=var)
    c.grid(row=index, sticky=tk.W)
    button_dict[field] = var    # save reference to the variable 

b = tk.Button(root, text="Submit_data", command=my_function_01)
b.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: fantastic , this is what i was looking for , i tried a lot to find a way to add a variable but did not find it.